# Toast not displaying onButtonClick

Tags: android, toast

I have a toast that should display anytime my "submit" button is pressed:

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public void ButtonOnClick(View view){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosautoreply", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
        TextView tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
        String message = tvMessage.getText().toString();
        editor.putString("message", message).commit();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated Successfully", 10);
    }
```

Here is my layout:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editMessage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="ButtonOnClick"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

There are no errors or logcats to display. The submit appears to function, but it doesn't Toast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated Successfully", 10).show();
```

Comment: for others who'll see this post `getApplicationContext()` is not recommended, try using `YOUACTIVITY.this`

Answer (score 4):

You have to call the show method on Toast to make it display something

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated Successfully", 10).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

its because, You have to call the show method on Toast to make it display something like:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated Successfully", 10).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `show()` on the Toast after making it, otherwise it will never be displayed. I'm curious as to why you suppressed the warnings for this; if you had simply listened to Eclipse, you would have seen the error and been able to correct it yourself.

Comment: I don't know how I could suppress the warning. I haven't changed any settings like that.

Comment: Your very first line `@SuppressLint("ShowToast")` suppresses the warning that Eclipse would normally show you when you create a Toast but do not show it.